# Server [500] Response from aspx POST query by BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

this is my first question on this site so forgive me if it's a poor one. I've used bs4 to scrape some basic HTML pages before, but this is my first time attempting to scrape results from a query and I'm struggling.

I'm interested in querying the Pennsylvania Department of Natural Resources database to track new gas well permits every day in my county. I will use datetime strftime to adjust the date to be current every day, and output the data from this:
[output table][image: 1]

From my understanding, I am passing a post request to the server using the post parameters specified in the input fields, and it will return the output I'm interested in. I've also created a variable containing request headers. When I pass these parameters and header into a request, it returns a 500 server error. I am writing this out in a python 3 Jupyter notebook.

```
#site to query
url = 'http://cedatareporting.pa.gov/Reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPublic%2fDEP%2fOG%2fSSRS%2fPermits_Issued_Detail'

#headers from output .aspx on examine webpage
headers= {'Accept':'*/*',
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
          'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}

#start new session
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url,headers=headers)

#create soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

#ASP validation and session fields
view_state = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
view_state_generator = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']
# there is not an event validation parameter on this site
#event_validation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

#this is every single parameter that appeared on the form data section.
post_params = {'AjaxScriptManager': 'AjaxScriptManager|ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl00',
'NavigationCorrector$ScrollPosition':'', 
'NavigationCorrector$ViewState':'', 
'NavigationCorrector$PageState': '',
'NavigationCorrector$NewViewState': '',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl03$ctl00':'', 
'ReportViewerControl$ctl03$ctl01':'', 
'ReportViewerControl$ctl10': 'ltr',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl11': 'standards',
'ReportViewerControl$AsyncWait$HiddenCancelField': 'False',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue': '11/4/2020',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue': '11/18/2020',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$ddValue': '31',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl09$ddValue': '1',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl11$ddValue': '1',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl13$ddValue': '1',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl15$ddValue': '2',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl17$txtValue': 'COALBED METHANE,COMB. OIL&GAS,DRY HOLE,GAS,INJECTION,MULTIPLE WELL BORE TYPE,OBSERVATION,OIL,STORAGE WELL,TEST WELL,UNDETERMINED,WASTE DISPOSAL',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl17$divDropDown$ctl01$HiddenIndices': '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11',
'ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$store':'' ,
'ReportViewerControl$ToggleParam$collapse': 'false',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl05$ctl00$CurrentPage': '1',
'null': '100',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00':'' ,
'ReportViewerControl$ctl08$ClientClickedId':'' ,
'ReportViewerControl$ctl07$store':'' ,
'ReportViewerControl$ctl07$collapse': 'false',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$VisibilityState$ctl00': 'ReportPage',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ScrollPosition':'', 
'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl02': '',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl03':'', 
'ReportViewerControl$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl04': '100',
'__EVENTTARGET': '',
'__EVENTARGUMENT':'', 
'__LASTFOCUS':'', 
'__VIEWSTATE': view_state,
'__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl00': 'View Report'}

#POST form fields
r = session.get(url,data=post_params,headers=headers)
error = bs(r.content, 'html')
```

Which returns this error message.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Power BI Report Server
  </title>
  <meta content="Microsoft Power BI Report Server 15.0.1103.234" name="Generator" />
  <meta content="500" name="HTTP Status" />
  <meta content="127" name="ProductLocaleID" />
  <meta content="1033" name="CountryLocaleID" />
  <style>
    BODY {
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      FONT-WEIGHT: normal;
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      COLOR: black
    }
    
    H1 {
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      FONT-WEIGHT: 700;
      FONT-SIZE: 15pt
    }
    
    LI {
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      FONT-WEIGHT: normal;
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      DISPLAY: inline
    }
    
    .ProductInfo {
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      COLOR: gray
    }
    
    A:link {
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      COLOR: #3366CC;
      TEXT-DECORATION: none
    }
    
    A:hover {
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      COLOR: #FF3300;
      TEXT-DECORATION: underline
    }
    
    A:visited {
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      COLOR: #3366CC;
      TEXT-DECORATION: none
    }
    
    A:visited:hover {
      FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
      FONT-FAMILY: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      color: #FF3300;
      TEXT-DECORATION: underline
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
  <h1>
    Report Server Error
    <hr color="silver" size="1" width="100%" />
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <li>For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors</li>
    <hr color="silver" size="1" width="100%" /><span class="ProductInfo">Power BI Report Server</span>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm unsure if something is disabled on the server side that is preventing this from returning the output I want, or if something is wrong with my request or parameters. I've referenced a lot of different examples, and I still can't get it. I just want to run a simple automated query, I have no desire to crawl the entire database. Thank you for reading my post. I look forward to your advice on my code as well as how to be a good member of stackoverflow.